# C program to mkdir in POSIX shared memory missing permissions

Tags: c, linux, permissions, posix, mkdir

I have a POSIX shared memory directory which gets blown away on reboot and needs to be recreated on occasion. An example,

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    struct stat st = {0};
    if (stat("/dev/shm/example", &st) == -1) {
        mkdir("/dev/shm/example", 0777);
    }
}
```

This creates the directory with missing write permissions for group/others:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 *** *** *** May 14 12:00 example
```

I've tried experimenting with the mode_t flags and even replaced "0777" with "S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO". I do need the directory to have permission flag 0777.

Comment: I do not recommend directly messing with `/dev/shm` Why not use API functions for that (`shm_open()` and friends)?

Comment: I did think the same and started with shm_open having the O_CREAT flag and was only able to create files. I'm not sure that shm_open can create directories.

Comment: You do not need to worry about `/dev/shmem` at all. Just use POSIX shmem APIs for all your needs.

Comment: Thank you for reading and responding, but I'm not sure what you mean. It seems the POSIX shm facilities defined by sys/mman.h does not support directory creation. If it does support directory creation, then I'm not seeing it. Every usage for shm_open does not create directories but it only creates files which need to be truncated and whatnot.

Comment: I am trying to understand why you need to do **anything** with `/dev/shm` directory. Which is your use case which doesn't allow you to simply use Posix shared memory API directly and forget about `/dev/shm`?

Comment: When using shm_open "and friends", it uses /dev/shm for it's POSIX memory. Is there anything about the POSIX API that disallows treating /dev/shm as you would any other directory? As for use case, suffice to say that's how my application is being implemented.

Comment: `/dev/shm` just happens to be directory which is mounted to tmpfs. It is not mandated by Posix, moreover, I would not be surprised to learn that you can have a linux running without `/dev/shm` being mounted. In essence, it is implementation detail. On the other hand, Posix shmem api is fixed and mandated to be implemented. I understand your application is implemented in this way, but this is unusual way to implement shared memory communication, so I am asking why it was done.

Comment: Your application should not be creating anything explicitly anywhere under `/dev`; that is the system's territory and you should not be messing around with it — not least because it gets cleaned up when your system is rebooted (or upgraded — though as that involves a reboot too, it amounts to much the same thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the permission explicitly or reset your [file creation mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) with the [`umask()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html).

Per the [POSIX `mkdir()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html) (bolding mine):

> The `mkdir()` function shall create a new directory with name path. The file permission bits of the new directory shall be initialized from mode. **These file permission bits of the mode argument shall be modified by the process' file creation mask.**

The only thread-safe way to create a file or directory with the exact permissions you want is to explicitly set them after creation:

```
mkdir("/dev/shm/example", 0777);
chmod("/dev/shm/example", 0777);
```

Of course, you'd do well to actually check the return values for those calls.

Calling [`umask()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) to set and restore your file creation mask **is not thread-safe**:

```
mode_t old = umask( 0 );
mkdir("/dev/shm/example", 0777);
umask( old );
```

There are multiple race conditions possible with doing that:

- The `old` mask you get with the first call to `umask()` can be the `0` set by another thread
- Either call can overwrite the value of the file creation mask currently in use by another thread

If either of those race conditions happens, either

- your file/directory won't get the permissions you need
- the other thread's file/directory won't get the permissions it needs
- the original file creation mask setting will be lost

Or all three.

So don't call `umask()` when you need to set permission bits exactly.  Set the mode explicitly with a call to [`[f]chmod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html)

(The possible issues that could arise from creating directories in `/dev/shm` is probably worth another question...)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Andrew. Although I do wonder about the wisdom of treating /dev/shm this way e.g. with functionality not defined by mman.h . Although I don't see anything in the APIs that immediately makes it a bad idea.